# Searching a word within a list, then taking all the strings between two points in the list

Tags: java, string, list, search

I have a huge list of names, I need to search for a word or number within this list and then take out all the strings in a seperate list.

The list is like this.

|Mary Jane, 1990, Brown|,|Henry Rollings, 1974, Red|

If I for example search "Mary", then everything should be taken out between the |'s and put in a seperate list. If one more Mary exists in this list then that needs to be taken out aswell. I first thought of using subStringSplit() when a name was found, but I failed miserably.

If anyone wants to read my shoddy coding, then http://data.fuskbugg.se/skalman02/6acb2a0c_DATABASGENERATOR.txt

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe use something like http://lucene.apache.org/ ?

Comment: If you describe the problem exactly, I believe there will be a better solution, try using a real example of what the list has and what the exact output will be.

Comment: |Blont, 1988, Adam Moloudnjead|, |Rött, 1978, Daniel Johannson| thats an example of that list, If I search for "Adam" then everything between the |'s should be taken out and saved in another list. I hope I'm clear now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the regular expression Matcher for such tasks.

Here is a code sample which should do the trick:

```
String inputList = "|Mary Jane, 1990, Brown|,|Henry Rollings, 1974, Red|,|Mary Mary Mary, 1974, Red|,|Someone Else, 1974, Red|";
        StringBuffer listWithMatchesRemoved = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer matchedItems = new StringBuffer();
        String searchString = "Mary";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([|][^|]*?"+searchString+"[^|]*?[|]),?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(inputList);

        while(m.find())
        {
            if(matchedItems.length()!=0)
                matchedItems.append(",");
            matchedItems.append(m.group(1));

            m.appendReplacement(listWithMatchesRemoved, "");
        }
        m.appendTail(listWithMatchesRemoved);

        System.out.println("Matches:" + matchedItems);
        System.out.println("The rest:" + listWithMatchesRemoved);
```

Comment: Swap out StringBuffer for StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test, but this should work. Tell me if this does not work.

EDIT: I made the code a bit better/cleaner.

```
List<String> searchFor(String search) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(YOUR_HUGE_LIST);
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (int index = 0; (index = builder.indexOf(search, index)) != -1; ){
        final int start = builder.lastIndexOf("|", index);

        index = builder.indexOf("|", index);

        list.add(builder.substring(start + 1, index));
        builder.delete(start, index + 1);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Looking at this more, I could see this having some bugs in edge cases, but this should still get you in the right direction.

Comment: I try to use this code but I can't write the name of my list in in (YOUR_HUGE_LIST). It gives me an error, it can't find the class of "stringbuilder". (Im using netbeans)